# why doesn't the append command work in my script?

Tags: bash, solaris

I have the following piece of code in a script in bash at solaris where `>>` *(append)* is not working meaning:

```
for j in $(cat file1.txt); do
    for i in $(cat file2.txt); do
    if [ "$j" = "$i" ]; then
        echo "_$i" >> file3.txt
    fi
    done
done
```

I don't know why `file3.txt` is not generated

Comment: if you remove `>> file3.txt`, does it print anything?

Comment: It's not answering the question per se, but you could do the same using the 'comm' command - http://www.ss64.com/bash/comm.html

Comment: It's likely that your input files are different, i.e. line `n` of each input file is different.

Comment: Not only every line, seems every word in the two files are different. The output of `$(cat file.txt)` will undergo word splitting and so every word in the first file will be compared against every word in second file.

Comment: Should this be `"$j" == "$i"` ? or `"$j" != "$i"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have no error message showing up while running your script, the `>>` redirection works just fine. The issue is the line using it just happen never to be called.

Just replace

```
if [ "$j" = "$i" ]; then
```

by

```
if [ "$j" != "$i" ]; then
```

to confirm it (assuming neither of `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` is empty).